# How will I store the block contents into an array or object?

Tags: javascript, views

Recently, I have an existing Slick Slideshow as a view created from the dashboard.

Right now, I wanted to just manage the slideshow from the backend and then display the slides in a different manner. So, what I have in mind is to store the slideshow data as an array or object and then from there I can freely manipulate/control how would I want my slides to be displayed.

Currently, when I use `print_r()` the slideshow displayed is already an html markup, I want to get the raw data of the slideshows in an array or an object. How would I do that? I am by the way a `Drupal 7` newbie. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `I want to get the raw data` you can remove all the markup with the PHP function called [strip_tags()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp)

Comment: @NoSssweat, thank you for the suggestion but `strip_tags()` is not what I need. Basically, when I use it, it still displays the data as an html markup. What I need is store the data in an array, in my case, store each slide details inside an array looking like `Array = ( 'slideshow1' => 'details' )` something like that.

Comment: Then I think you are looking for this [How can I save arrays of values in the database?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53318/how-can-i-save-arrays-of-values-in-the-database)

Comment: @NoSssweat, I am trying to store data into an array, not the other way around.

Comment: @NoSssweat, Nevermind that, I think I have got the answer. Thank you man.

Comment: @TsukimotoMitsumasa, did you understand the answer because of the question that NoSssweat posted in the comment above?